# If statement with language tree in prolog

Tags: if-statement, tree, prolog

I currently am generating a prolog tree with input such as:

```
the flight flew.
```

whose tree looks like this:

```
s(the, np(flight), vp(flew))
```

After I generate said tree I am attempting to check if, in this case, "the" is in fact "the". There is another case where it could be "did".

As far as I'm aware, a prolog if statement is formatted like:

```
( IF -> THEN; ELSE ),
```

and I'm trying to do:

```
( s(the, A, B)) -> assert(Tree); do_something_else ),
```

but when I do that, I cannot run the program. How would I go about asking about a specific value in a tree in an if statement? Am I doing an if statement correctly in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot run the program"? Is there an error message? the statement per se is correct, but the surroundings might be erroneous. Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to give useful information on what actually happens when you try to run your actual program. In other words, learn how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you have your "tree" in a term like you show it, all you need is a rule that uses pattern matching (unification) in the head to check if the first argument of `s/3` is `the` or `did`:

```
foo(s(the, A, B)) :- /* do some stuff */.
foo(s(did, A, B)) :- /* do other stuff */.
```

This is probably better than using an if-then-else construct. If you insist, you would have to say something like:

```
T = s(Foo, A, B),
(   Foo == the
->  /* do something */
;   Foo == did
->  /* do something else */
;   /* anything else */
)
```

The point here is that the condition in the if-then-else has to be something that is evaluated and either succeeds or fails: you cannot use pattern matching as you do in the head of a predicate. Another roundabout way of writing the condition would be to use something like [`arg/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3):

```
(   arg(1, T, the)
->  /* ... */
;   arg(1, T, did)
->  /* ... */
;   /* ... */
)
```

But what is bothering me is that after parsing you end up with either an article, `the`, or a verb, `did`. What part of the sentence is the first argument of `s/3` supposed to represent?